# my python crawler is not working on some websites

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-crawler

My python crawler is not working in some websites. I cannot figure out what is the problem. I fetched many website and on most of them it perfectly fetched each and every link of that website. But on some websites my python web crawler is stuck on a loop.

My best guess some website contains "\" at the end of their link. My crawler saves its data or link in MySQL which give same links again and again to my crawler

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import MySQLdb as sql
import time
import warnings

print("starting")

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

db = sql.connect("localhost", "root", "arpit", "website")
cursor = db.cursor()
db.autocommit(True)

print("connected to database")

url = "http://www.example.com"
extension = ".com"
print("scrapping url -",url)

r = requests.head(url)
cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code)     
values(%s,'pending',%s)", [url, r.status_code])

cursor.execute("select status from urls where status ='pending' limit 1")
result = str(cursor.fetchone())

while (result != "None"):

cursor.execute("select urls from urls where status ='pending' limit 1")
result = str(cursor.fetchone())

s_url = result[2:-3]

cursor.execute("update urls set status = 'done' where urls= %s ", [s_url])

if "https" in url:
    url1 = url[12:]
else:
    url1 = url[11:]
zone = 0
while True:

    try:
        r = requests.get(s_url,timeout=60)
        break

    except:
        if s_url == "":

            print("done")
            break
        elif zone >= 4:
            print("this url is not valid -",s_url)
            break
        else:
            print("Oops!  may be connection was refused.  Try again...",s_url)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            zone = zone + 1

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')

links = soup.find_all("a")

for x in links:
    a = x.get('href')
    if a is not None and a != "":

        if a != "" and a.find("\n") != -1:
            a = a[0:a.find("\n")]

        if a != "" and a[-1] == "/":
            a = a[0:-1]

        if a != "":
            common_extension = [',',' ',"#",'"','.mp3',"jpg",'.wav','.wma','.7z','.deb','.pkg','.rar','.rpm','.tar','.zip','.bin','.dmg','.iso','.toast','.vcd','.csv','.dat','.log','.mdb','.sav','.sql','.apk','.bat','.exe','.jar','.py','.wsf','.fon','.ttf','.bmp','.gif','.ico','.jpeg','.png','.part','.ppt','.pptx','.class','.cpp','.java','.swift','.ods','.xlr','.xls','.xlsx','.bak','.cab','.cfg','.cpl','.dll','.dmp','.icns','.ini','.lnk','.msi','.sys','.tmp','.3g2','.3gp','.avi','.flv','.h264','.m4v','.mkv','.mov','.mp4','.mpg','.vob','.wmv','.doc','.pdf','.txt']
            for ext in common_extension:
                if ext in a:
                    a = ""
                    break

        if a != "":
            if a[0:5] == '/http':
                a = a[1:]
            if a[0:6] == '//http':
                a = a[2:]

            if a[0:len(url1) + 12] == "https://www." + url1:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [a, r.status_code])
            elif a[0:len(url1) + 11] == "http://www." + url1:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [a, r.status_code])
            elif a[0:len(url1) + 8] == "https://" + url1:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [url + (a[(a.find(extension + "/")) + 4:]), r.status_code])
            elif a[0:len(url1) + 7] == "http://" + url1:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [url + (a[(a.find(extension + "/")) + 4:]), r.status_code])
            elif a[0:2] == "//" and a[0:3] != "///" and "." not in a and "http" not in a and "www." not in a:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [url + a[1:], r.status_code])
            elif a[0:1] == "/" and a[0:2] != "//" and "." not in a and "http" not in a and "www." not in a:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [url + a[0:], r.status_code])
            elif 'http' not in a and 'www.' not in a and "." not in a and a[0] != "/":
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [url + '/' + a, r.status_code])

cursor.execute("alter table urls drop id")
cursor.execute("alter table urls add id int primary key not null  
auto_increment first")
print("new id is created")
```

Comment: Did you try adding a timeout?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes but still its not working

Comment: You guess is reasonable, you can try checking data in mysql when stucking.

Comment: can u debug to figure out which line is stuck